# Magic Find worse for finding unique/sets in Baal runs?

Tags: diablo-ii

It always seemed to me that if I do a Baal run without MF, I get more unique/sets and less rares.

So I thought to make a couple dozen runs on Baal Nightmare to see how it works.
After 15 runs without MF and 15 runs with 280 MF, I got more than twice unique/sets on the runs without MF.

Is this just a bizarre coincidence, or actually you have better chance of getting uniques without MF from bosses since the chance to drop rares is increased more than the chance to get uniques by MF?

However, on the official page I didn't find anything that would suggest this, but on the contrary magic find is better for finding uniques even for bosses.

I'm a little confused so can someone please clarify this.

Comment: Your sample size is too small. If you did 200 runs each, then the picture would be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) at work. People tend to try to draw patterns there there are none, because randomness doesn't make sense (as it shouldn't, really). You've gotten lucky on runs recently finding Set and Unique items, and nothing more. The drop rate for those is still lower than rares, and it's still improved by MF just like the drop rate for rares is.